# k8s intermittent "connection timed out"

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

In attempting to setup our application in minikube, I'm encountering some unexpected refused connections.  After widdling it down, I've got a redis pod and a generic application pod which includes netcat.

When I shell into the application pod, I use **nc** to test the connection.  It resolves the pod host correctly, and can sometimes connect, but at other times, intermittently, I'm getting connection refused.

```
while true; do
  sleep 1
  echo -n $(date)" "
  echo KEYS \* | nc redis 6379 | head -n1
done

# the result is:
...
Mon Mar 21 15:39:04 UTC 2022 *2
Mon Mar 21 15:39:05 UTC 2022 *2
Mon Mar 21 15:39:13 UTC 2022 Ncat: Connection timed out.
Mon Mar 21 15:39:24 UTC 2022 *2
Mon Mar 21 15:39:28 UTC 2022 Ncat: Connection timed out.
Mon Mar 21 15:39:39 UTC 2022 *2
Mon Mar 21 15:39:41 UTC 2022 *2
...
```

This happens from both a CentOS based PHP application image and from the Docker generic tutum/dnsutils image I'm using for netcat.

Since it sometimes works, I think I've got the pods setup right:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: redis-conf
data:
  redis-conf: |
    dir /var/lib/redis
    bind 0.0.0.0
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php
  labels:
    app: php
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php
        image: docker.io/library/php_php:latest
        #image: tutum/dnsutils
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
      initContainers:
      - name: set-redis-using-tutum
        image: tutum/dnsutils
        command: ["sh", "-c", "echo SET tutum tutumval | nc redis 6379"]
      - name: get-redis-using-tutum
        image: tutum/dnsutils
        command: ["sh", "-c", "echo GET tutum | nc redis 6379"]
      - name: set-redis-using-php
        image: docker.io/library/php_php:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        command: ["sh", "-c", "echo SET php phpval | nc redis 6379"]
      - name: get-redis-using-php
        image: docker.io/library/php_php:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        command: ["sh", "-c", "echo GET php | nc redis 6379"]
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: php
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: redis
        image: redis:5.0.4
        command: ["redis-server", "/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/redis
          name: redis-data
        - mountPath: /etc/redis
          name: redis-conf
      volumes:
      - name: redis-data
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: redis-conf
        configMap:
          name: redis-conf
          items:
          - key: redis-conf
            path: redis.conf
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  selector:
    app: php
  ports:
  - port: 6379
    targetPort: 6379
```

Comment: Could you please add an 'events' section from the `kubectl describe pods <your pod>` output for Redis and application pods? Also, are there any errors in the logs for Redis? Are your pods running without restarts?